# JasperReports - É possível que um relatório seja listado diversas vezes automaticamente?

Tags: java, java-ee, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Tenho um relatório que nada mais é que uma nota fiscal, com seus itens e dados da nota e dos itens. Foi pedida uma funcionalidade que ao selecionar mais de uma nota fiscal, esse relatório gere o template de cada nota em um PDF só para que o usuário imprima massivamente a lista de notas selecionadas.

Olhei o site do JasperReports e tentei utilizar sub relatórios copiando o conteúdo do outro JRXML (fonte do iReport), tentei algum método de usar esse JRXML como conteúdo incorporado ao outro relatório listando meus objetos em cima dos mesmo, mas também sem sucesso. É possível que isso seja feito? Caso positivo, como?

Comment: O correto é utilizar o subreport, publique o seu jrxml e suas classes para que posso analisar.

Comment: Quais classes você quer? Eu já consigo passar o objeto JSON para o relatório individual com sucesso. E também consigo passar uma lista de objetos JSON para o outro relatório também sem problemas, só não consigo gerar a lista de relatórios sendo lido cada um destes objetos.

Comment: Quero ver como você esta passando a sua classe 'nota fiscal' para jasper e os jrxmls em si.

Answer (score 0):

Se são vários relatórios e você deseja apenas exportar todos juntos você pode usar o exemplo de batch export do jasper conforme este link: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html

Um possível exemplo seria:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrintList);
    pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, os);
    pdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_CREATING_BATCH_MODE_BOOKMARKS, Boolean.TRUE);
    pdfExporter.exportReport();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
```

Onde jasperPrintList seria uma lista de objetos do tipo JasperPrint que você consegue dando fill no relatório da seguinte maneira

```
JasperPrint impressao = JasperFillManager.fillReport("caminho_do_arquivo_jasper", new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
```